# C# Equivalent of Spring @ModelAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am a Java/Spring dev new to C#/Entity Framework and was wondering if there was a C# equivalent to Springs `@ModelAttribute` Annotation

ex:
In a java controller/servlet I can do

```
@ModelAttribute("form")
public IContactForm getContactForm() {
    return new ContactForm();
}
```

or something like

```
@ModelAttribute("list")
public List getItems() {
    return new ArrayList( ... );
}
```

and in the view/markup - reference said attribute by

```
<form:form path="myField">
```

or ( pseduo )

```
<select>
    for (String s : list) {
        <option value="${s}" />
    }
</select>
```

Then, if i were to post said form I could create the ContactForm object through the use of `@ModelAttribute() IContactForm form`

ex:

```
public void handleJsonPost( @Valid @ModelAttribute("form") IContactForm form) { 
    String x = form.getAField();
}
```

So, to reiterate the quesiton, does .NET/Entity Framework have a built in functionality like Springs `@ModelAttribute` or is there a Nuget package I can download? ...or anything at all?

Comment: No there is not an equivalent attribute. In ASP MVC, you can pass any class to your view as a model. That model can have attributes. The markup syntax you are after can be achieved using [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using the Razor view engine. I suggest you reference this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers-forms-and-validation) to get started and scroll down to "Task 2 - Creating the Edit View" if you want to dive straight into forms.